# How to remove Hyper-v from a Windows 7 machine?

Tags: windows-7, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I installed Hyper-v 2008 r2 on a Windows 7 box thinking it works like Virtual PC because I wanted to run a Windows 2008 R2 64 vm. Now my machine dual boots between Windows 7 and hyper-v.

How do I completely remove hyper-v and get the box back to the state before the install?

Comment: wow didn't even think it would let you start the install.. so you did the add remove programs and you still see evidence of hyper-v

Comment: There's no trace of it inside Windows 7. I started the installation from Win7, told it to install on another disk partition. Now Hyper-v runs as a stand alone OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used easybcd and deleted the entry from the boot manager. Now it's just a matter of deleting the folder(s).

Answer (score -1):

Delete the partition in Disk Management, and use BCDEdit from an admin command line to update your boot options.

Answer (score -3):

You format your discs, reinstall windows 7 and realizes that reading at least the product description before installing something may not be the smost stupid thing onthis planet to do.

How the hell did you ever miss out that the installer looks like a windows system installer and not like a program installer?

Comment: It looked like a regular program installer. It installed while inside Windows 7 and your answer is utterly useless.

Comment: It is not useless - you may not like it, but as you were so "unsmart" to install a second operating system without looking (note: installer does not like like a normal windows installer - I just tested) a complete reinstall WILL fix it. YOu may not like it, but then it is not a law of nature that people doing stupid things get what they want ;)

Comment: "Smart" people try to help people instead of posting snide comments. 
Since you are "smart"!, a complete reinstall is totally unnecessary. Just delete the OS entry in the boot manager. It just proves that people who think are smart are really not. sheesh.

Comment: and most people don't read full product descriptions. They learn about some product, they install it and if they don't want it, they uninstall it. I guess they are not smart like you!